# Search Entire Worksheet and Return Cell Value of the Matched Column

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

Using Google Sheets, how do I search the entire contents of one worksheet, and return a value from a specific cell when a match occurs? You can assume that the worksheet that will be searched on has unique values.

For example: I have a worksheet that contains players that belong to two different teams. On the other worksheet, I have a list of all the players, and I would like the matched team name to show up next to the player.

In the linked example, I want to search the "Teams" worksheet and return the value of Row 2 (the name of the team) in the cell next to the player (in the "Team Name" column in the "Search" worksheet).

If the formula is working, I would expect to see "Team A" next to "Smith, Bob" in the "Search" worksheet.

[Google Worksheet Teams](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hPYt7xyIdqTtDlYbCNGc98z9s7hLnpCf5uWOuIcpgTI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suggesting a formula like this:

=INDEX(Teams!$2:$2;0;SUM(IF(Teams!$A$3:$B$5=$A2;COLUMN(Teams!$A$3:$B$5)-MIN(COLUMN(Teams!$A$3:$B$5))+1;0)))

where

- Teams - is the name of worksheet with team and team member names
- $2:$2 - is 2nd row in Teams worksheet holding team names
- $A$3:$B$5 - is table holding all player names (team names are one row above this table)
- $A2 - player name that we are looking for.

In MS excel:
Type the formula, and then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

In Google-spreadsheet:

Write it inside ArrayFormula() function like this
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(Teams!$2:$2,0,SUM(IF(Teams!$A$3:$B$5=$A2,COLUMN(Teams!$A$3:$B$5)-MIN(COLUMN(Teams!$A$3:$B$5))+1,0))))

[Google Worksheet Teams Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HON6CsBMh2ncx1y75Oi2VydlyjcIV8xcXLH1XUOWQls/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- your search criteria is in column A on the search sheet.
- The sheets containing the teams is called 'Teams' and team names are in column B.
- Player names are in column A on 'Teams'.

  =INDEX(Teams!B:B, MATCH(A:A, Teams!A:A,0))